# How can I use my retrieved access_token with the Googles Credential Builder instead of a service account

Tags: coldfusion, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I am using the Google Drive API V2 with the Java Library in ColdFusion. It is from this project (which is old) https://github.com/PCommons/cf-google-drive.

The code is written to work with a service account, but I want to use an access_token and have the oAuth part already working to get an access_token.  But I can't get past the part where the credential_builder is called:

```
Credential_Builder  = server.javaLoader.create("com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder");

 credential = Credential_Builder
 .setTransport(variables.HTTP_Transport)
 .setJsonFactory(variables.JSON_Factory)
 .setServiceAccountId(variables.serviceAccountEmail)
 .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(variables.Drive_Scopes.DRIVE))
 .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(variables.File_Obj.Init(variables.pathToKeyFile))
 .build()
```

I would like to be able to provide my access_token instead of setServiceAccountId() and setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(). I can't find any documentation that shows how the CredentialBuilder class can be used with an access_token.

Note, in the code from this project, once the credentials are instaniated, the code below is called:

```
variables.Drive_Builder
        .setApplicationName(applicationName)
        .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
        .build()
```

Is there a different instance I need to use and provide to setHttpRequestInitializer()?

Comment: This link might help  https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-api-client/latest/com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential  . It shows the 3 types of authentication: access token only, refresh token flow, and service account flow . It shouldn't be too hard to adapt the code to use method 1 or 2.

Comment: @SOS - dude! This helped me so much!!! I am so grateful, thank you!!

Comment: Glad it was helpful! Feel free to post an answer with your final code, If you think it'll help someone else.